# How can I open my local TCP port to public?

Tags: networking, tcp, server, client, port

I have a TCP Server for a my personal chat, I want to expand my connection beyond my local network and I want to open my port: 28752 to my IP public of pc to enter wherever I want only when my computer is on.
I have seen different solutions for example DMZ to associate my local IP to public IP, but i want to do this without modifying to router's setting I wanted to do it from a program. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to open up ports. But it depends on the OS in which you are trying to accomplish it. You can use the linux iptables to manipulate the ports opened and closed to any linux machine. [Iptables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables)[Some examples](https://www.howtogeek.com/177621/the-beginners-guide-to-iptables-the-linux-firewall/) . The ports should also be opened on the firewall layer outside the VM. eg: It could be AWS access policy, Security group, MAC's security firewall. Your laptop, when connected to the internet, will have a public IP address, you can share that public IP. But these IP address will change when you get connected to a different router. You can use AWS cli commands to assign a static IP address for your machine and expose it publicly. At the least minimum, you would need a public DNS server to expose your IP publicly.  Easy way to achieve this is by putting in web server on cloud. Without a domain , you cant expose your IP. Once you have finalized on the domain (eg: AWS Route 53, Ingree IP from K8 etc), you can change/manipulate them from your program. It need not be language specific.